# Nullable object must have a value - vb date fields

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Okay, none of the previous questions I have seen with this error seem to apply in this situation.

tEmp is a class that contains (among other things) two nullable date fields.

```
Public Property InsuranceEligibleDate As Nullable(Of Date)
Public Property NextReview As Nullable(Of Date)
```

During a routine on my form, I am attempting to see if the following conditions are true...

```
If Not IsNothing(tEmp.NextReview.Value) Or tEmp.ReviewReason <> "" Or Not IsNothing(tEmp.InsuranceEligibleDate.Value) Then
    blah blah blah
End If
```

I get the above error (the title of question), but when I hover over the debugger, NextReview and InsuranceEligibleDate are both Nothing (which is correct for the employee I am looking at).  What am I missing?

I am using VB2010, and the Properties in the Employee class are using the new way of declaring Properties (i.e. no set/get)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem that I encountered a while back with the use of the `Or` operator. Using simply `Or` will still cause both sides of the expression to be evaluated. So if the first portion is a null check and the second portion is based on that null check, the second will STILL fail because it is still evaluated. Proper usage would be to use the `OrElse` operator like below (oh, and you should be using the `.HasValue` property as well for the nullable). One other note is that you should be using `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` to evaluate the empty string rather than `<>`. For 3.5 it is `String.IsNullOrEmpty`.

```
If tEmp.NextReview.HasValue OrElse Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tEmp.ReviewReason) OrElse tEmp.InsuranceEligibleDate.HasValue Then
    blah blah blah
End If
```

Comment: You want `If tEmp.NextReview.HasValue`, no `Not` keyword ;-)

Comment: @Meta-Knight: Thanks. Typing too quickly I didn't proofread the code result.

Comment: As always, quick and fast solutions.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the value from a potentially empty value, you need to do the check like this:

```
If Not tEmp.NextReview.HasValue Or tEmp.ReviewReason <> "" Or Not tEmp.InsuranceEligibleDate.HasValue Then
    blah blah blah
End If
```

Comment: You want `If tEmp.NextReview.HasValue`, no `Not` keyword ;-)

Comment: Also, you should get in the habit of using `OrElse` (short-circuiting Or) instead of `Or`

Answer (score 1):

When using `Nullable` the thing to check to see if a value is present is `.HasValue`.

So your code would better be put as:

```
If tEmp.NextReview.HasValue Or tEmp.ReviewReason <> "" Or tEmp.InsuranceEligibleDate.HasValue Then
    blah blah blah
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

When you check for Nothing by using value you get the exception because you tried accessing a property on a null object. Use the HasValue property instead to determine if there's a value.